# Why are curved triangles not considered as triangles?

Tags: terminology

I asked a question on the math side where it was said that this is a philosophical question. So here it is. Why are curved triangles, in Euclidean space, not considered triangles? The only case of a curved triangle is a [Reuleaux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reuleaux_triangle) triangle, which is a highly symmetric one. Why not consider arbitrarily formed triangles, with arbitrarily formed sides and angles that can add up to values above or below 180 degrees? "Normal" triangles and the Reulaux one can then be considered as special cases of a generalized triangle.

Answer (score 1):

*Nothing philosophical either*...

It is tradition; see Euclid's [Elements](https://mathcs.clarku.edu/%7Edjoyce/elements/bookI/bookI.html), **Bk.I**:

> **Definition 14**. A *figure* is that which is contained by any boundary or boundaries.

Thus, a figure may have a curved boundary.

> **Definition 19**. *Rectilinear* figures are those which are contained by straight lines, trilateral figures being those contained by three, quadrilateral those contained by four, and multilateral those contained by more than four straight lines.

---

Having said that, in mathematics we have a sort of "dialectic" between precise definition and generalization.

Comment: But mathematics has certainly developed beyond Elements? Why do mathematicians stick to old tradition(s)?

Comment: Doesn't the concept of curved triangles give something new?

Comment: @Methadont - it hase. See e.g. [spherical triangle](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/SphericalTriangle.html#:~:text=A%20spherical%20triangle%20is%20a,(Harris%20and%20Stocker%201998).)

Answer (score 0):

It's with taking a moment to think about the ramifications of what this question asks. For instance, allowing a triangle to have curved sides would mean that we could not distinguish between a triangle whose sides have a particular radius of curvature and a circle. In fact, we could take a circle, pick an arbitrary set of points on its circumference and call them vertices, and then claim our circle was in fact a triangle, or a quadrilateral, or a quintilateral... Further, by artfully constructing a triangle with two straight sides and one curved side (with a right-angle curve in it), we can turn our triangle into a rectangle and vice-versa. Allowing curved sides effectively erases the distinctions between all the basic geometric shapes.

Ancient mathematicians based their work on 'compass and straight-edge' geometry. They used straight lines and arcs of circles to make all their measurements and calculations, and so our geometry is (traditionally) based on straight-sided figures and evolutes of circles. They could have used a different basis for geometry, I imagine, but they didn't, and this preference for straight-edged figures has persisted. But if they had, they would have created a different set of 'basic' figures that made sense within that system. One way or the other we have to make definitional assertions and work from that standpoint. Calling the definitional assertions into question merely creates heat without adding light.

Comment: You could consider a circle to be a special case of a generalized triangle. As one for which all angles are the same (180 degrees) and the lengths of all sides are the same (as their form).